# Installing (minimal) MySQL Workbench to simply join data from two .csv files (connections???)

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-10, mysql-workbench

I previously used MySQL Workbench to do this, in an environment that was already set up.

How do I set up a minimal working environment to just create and join tables on my own computer? (Connections???)

More details:

I downloaded and installed MySQL Workbench, and I can't even run SELECT sysdate();. There's a red x next to it.  If I try "CREATE DATABASE MY_DATABASE; there's a green check, but the execute button is grey.

Doing some reading I apparently need "connections."  Reading about that, I apparently need to also install MySQL Database Server.  Who knows what else.

So, again, the question is how do I set up a minimally working environment to just create tables from .csv files, join them with MySQL commands, and export the results to another .csv file?  (I know the syntax of the command to import a .csv file, and how to join tables.)

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that MySQL server and MySQL Workbench is all that you need, so you are 1/2 way there.

Comment: I did that.  I'm still not connected.  This version of MySQL is *SO* different.  I built a table (not using a CREATE TABLE ... command but by filling in the fields - that's new).  I created a script to load the .csv file in the same place I made the table, and there is no button to run it.  I exited out of model creation to the startup window, and selected 'open script.'  Now there's a run button, but it's greyed.  The top left of the screen says "unconnected."  From the menu, Server->Client Connections does absolutely nothing.  So how do I load the data from the .csv file into the table?

Comment: I don't have Workbench installed at the moment, but try closing and relaunching Workbench. From what I recall that last time that I used it (has been a couple, if not a few years), somewhere in the tool there is a way to connect to the DB so that you can do those operations. If that still doesn't work, post another comment, and I'll install Workbench to see what might be the deal.  Oh, what versions of MySQL server and Workbench do you have installed?

Comment: I installed the newest one.  I restarted, selected connect to database, and selected the connection I named "Local" at setup (127.0.0.1 ...).   Now I see a windows that is populated.  When I try to run my load script from the Model window - it says I can't do that there - and I need to run it in a script shell.  When I copy the script over to the first Wndows (connected to Local) and try to run it, it says I'm not connected to a database, and the database should be in the schema list to the left.  It isn't there.  There's "sys" and a search box.  Searching for my table name fails.

Comment: Ok, I'll install MySQL Workbench 6.3.9...

Comment: For the scripting, there's a menu option: `Scripting` => `Scripting Shell` ... is that where you tried?

Comment: I found [this information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html) about Workbench, but I do not see the import/export options that they show to be available, do you?

Comment: I finally got this working.  You have to manually initialize (one time only) and then start the server from a command prompt (mysqld --initialize; mysqld), and in the model creation window you have to select Database->Forward Engineer (rather obscure, IMO), and then the schema will show up in the main window where you can load an execute scripts.

Comment: I'm using "load data local infile ..." to import.  I don't know if there's any automated functionality.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention to ensure the `mysqld` is running. You can set the MySQLd to run after the system starts so that you don't have to manually launch that each time, use `services.msc` to set it. I found the options mentioned earlier. After launching Workbench, choose the DB connection. After the Workbench loads, to the left of the `Query` window, there are `SCHEMAS` in a small `Navigator` section. Choose a DB in that list, expand the sub option `Tables`. Right click on one of the tables, and the import/export options will appear in the context menu.

Comment: You can also right-click on a DB in the `SCHEMAS` list, to find: `Table Data Import Wizard` in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install MySQL WorkBench *AND* MySQL Server.
2. From the command line, in the directory where MySQL server is installed, execute "mysqld --initialize"  (One time only.)
3. execute "mysqld" from the command line, after the initialization given in step 1, and after any reboots.  (It runs in the background, and doesn't exit when you exit MySQL WorkBench.  (It can optionally be installed as an automatically running Windows service during installation.)
4. Execute Database -> Connect to Database upon starting MySQL WorkBench (each time you start the application).  The default local host connection works fine.
5. After doing File -> New Model and setting up table(s), do Database -> Forward Engineer.  This will place your new database in the Schemas section on the home/main window.
6. Double click on the Schema you created (default name is mydb) and it changes to bold font.  Now scripts you run from that main window will run against the database you created.